# How come a company partners with Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, legal, community

I was checking out the Bitcoin website, and I've noticed something that I can't stomach :

> The Bitcoin network is growing at an impressive rate and Bitcoin.com
>   is forming new and lasting **partnerships** within the industry. Here
>   are some companies we are working with who are fostering a healthy
>   ecosystem.

I believe that Bitcoin is not a private company and it's owned by its community, right ? How is it possible for a company to partner with Bitcoin ?

Comment: I would like to point out the bitcoin.com (last I checked) is in fact not to do with Bitcoin but, actually Bitcoin Cash. An important distinction. The primary resource for Bitcoin is [bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org/).

Comment: It seems that some people are trying to take advantage of the Bitcoin fame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I was checking out the Bitcoin website

There is no such thing. There are various communities and privately-run sites, but they are all distinct, and none are authoritative.

> I believe that Bitcoin is not a private company

That's correct.

> it's owned by its community

That's a matter of perspective. I would say it's not owned by anyone - not even any specific community.

> How is it possible for a company to partner with Bitcoin ?

They're not partnering with Bitcoin. They're partnering with bitcoin.com, a privately-owned and controversial website.

Comment: You hit the bullseye, I was checking out bitcoin.com. Thank you so much, that makes sense now.